# Google AdWords Location Criterion Id to ISO 3166-2

Tags: php, highcharts, google-ads-api

Is there a way to obtain the ISO 3166-2 code for a specific location received from the [Geo Performance Report](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/geo-performance-report) coming from the Google AdWords API?

I need to show a map chart representing countries and those javascript libraries work with ISO Codes.

For example:

API response:

```
{"Country\/Territory":"2724","Region":"2724","Impressions":"7","Campaign_ID":"1234","Campaign":"video-campaign-test-5c4c476815a9c","Avg_Cost":"12344444","Avg_CPC":"0","Avg_CPM":"12344444","Avg_CPV":"12344444","Clicks":"0","Cost":"94550032","CTR":"0.00%","View_rate":"14.29%","Views":"1"}
```

So, I can get from the Region code, 2724 that it refers to the ISO code "ES".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an official CSV file that provides additional information about Adwords' Geolocations. Among other fields, you'll find the ISO-3166-1 alpha-2 country code for each location ID.

The file can be found here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geo/geotargets-2019-02-11.csv

Note that it is updated from time to time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is what I was looking for!